# TypeLoadException - how to proceed

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, unity-game-engine, mono

So I try to load my dependencies into my code, and then I get this:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' from assembly 'System.Data,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo.GetMethodInfo (IntPtr handle) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:59)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo.GetAttributes (IntPtr handle) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:75)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.get_Attributes () (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:245)
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase.get_IsSpecialName () (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:184)
>   UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces.InitializeBuildCallbacks
>   (Boolean findBuildProcessors, Boolean findSceneProcessors) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildPipelineInterfaces.cs:149)y

I'm using mono, so that may be the reason? I don't really know, since it's the first time I try to work with a database on Unity.

What could I do to make it work?

Comment: A `SqlConnection` won't work for for `mySql` anyway

Comment: so what should I use then? it's been a while since i last worked with a mysql database on .net framework

Comment: The dependencies i've loaded into the script are

- using System.Data;
- using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

Comment: You'd want to use a [`MySqlConnection`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-connection.html)

Comment: I'm using MySqlConnection, but it still gives me the same issue.

private static MySqlConnection dbConnection;

then i call this function just at the beggining

private static void openSqlConnection() {
  string connectionString = "Server='nameoftheserver';" +
   "Database='nameofthedb';" +
   "User ID='username;" +
   "Password='password';";
  dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
  dbConnection.Open();
  Debug.Log("Connected to database.");
 }

Am i doing something i shouldn't do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use **System.Data.dll** from one of {ProgramFilesDir/x86}\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\ Unity profiles (e.g., Unity "Subset v3.5") folders?

Did you put it in "Assets/**/Plugins" folder?

Error tells you that you'r developing with other assembly version that you build / run (in other enviroment) your app.

Comment: Yes, i tried with the one that's included with it and other i downloaded.

Comment: If you could zip this part of your project and give link to it would be easier. If you can.

Comment: Well thing is i'm not able to do this now, but once i solve a few issues i could be able to do that, meanwhile i'm trying to work with sqlite, which worked without issues to me so far